# Unnable to connect TSQLConnection to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, delphi, delphi-xe4

When I try to connect a `TSQLConnection` with `MSSQLConnection` it returns `dbxmss.dll` missing.

There is no such dll in all of my `C:` drive (I checked also `...\bin\` folder)

I've already uninstalled and reinstalled Delphi (XE4). 
And, after that, it is still missing.

The table was created with Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (v11.0.3128.0) Management Studio.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Surely you meant `TSQLConnection` right?

Comment: Missing drivers from Windows?

Comment: Seems that this dll should be in the Delphi bin folder. But, it doesn't.

Comment: Actually, I see that is missing another file, Data.DBXMSSQL.dcu. I dont know if is the same or other problem...

Comment: You must be using the Professional or lower SKU of RAD Studio. They don't come with SQL Server drivers for dbExpress. You'll need to use TADOConnection and TADOQuery instead (or upgrade to Enterprise/Architect).

Comment: Which flavour of Delphi XE4 do you have?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the Professional.

Comment: I tried to connect with ADOConnection. It works well.
I don't know if this kind of connection is slower,but I will try.

Thanks @KenWhite !

Comment: @KenWhite, shouldn't that be an answer?

Answer (score 1):

It appears you're using a Professional or lower SKU of RAD Studio. The lower editions don't come with drivers for SQL Server or Oracle for DBExpress.

You'll need to switch to using ADO (via the components in the dbGo component palette page), upgrade to a higher SKU (Enterprise or Architect), or find a third-party dbExpress driver to use instead.

Answer (score 0):

Download [Zip folder](http://wiltonsoftware.com/download/libmysql-5.1.59-win32.zip)
Extract libmysql.dll, Place it in the folder "C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\9.0\bin64